# Mysqli Extension missing

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, web-config

I have a Debian server on my Windows 7 host. I have been following this tutorial

https://jtreminio.com/2012/07/setting-up-a-debian-vm-step-by-step/

I have followed all the steps and currently in the process of using PhymyAdmin that I have recently installed. While PHPmyadmin it states that the Mysqli extension is missing. I have checked the phpinfo() and mysqli hasnt got its own section. I noticed in the tutorial on the link that it doesn't include `--with-mysqli`.

My PHP ini file I have uncommeted out the

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```

I have also filled in the default mysqli socket which points to the file

```
mysqli.default_socket = /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mysqli.so
```

I have run `./configure --with-mysqli`.

Still not showing Mysqli section on phpinfo().

Need some help on this, thanks.

Comment: There is no real reason to compile PHP from source unless you want the very latest and greatest, use the ones from the apt-repository instead

Answer (score 0):

> mysqli.default_socket = /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mysqli.so

mysqli.so is a library rather then a socket, which should be loaded via 'extension=...mysqli.so' in the file in conf.d

make sure you intalled php5-mysql

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

make sure you load mysqli.so library in

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysqli.ini
```

apt should have done everything for you already. last but not least,

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```